# Is it possible to play 360 Degrees Html5 videos working with gyroscope sensor on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, video, mobile, 360-degrees

Is it possible to play html5 360 degrees videos works with gyroscope on mobile browsers like facebook 360 degrees videos ?

I made some research. So far i found some plugins on github but they are not working with gyro. Axis, Valiant..

Comment: Yes. This is totally possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of research and lots of tests, i think best solution for selft hosted panoramic 360 degree video is Krpano plugin.
http://krpano.com/video/

There are some minor problems for in app browsers but it's usable.

Comment: You have to pay to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples available which you can do this with - for example:

- https://bitmovin.com/adaptive-vr-360-video-streaming-html5/

This works on Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS (it may work on other browser also - these are just the ones I happen to have used).

Answer (score 0):

There is 3D Vista, which is a powerful 360 virtual tour app. You can export your 360 footages (photos, videos + links) in a html5 folder with their own 360 player that you can put on your own hosting/server. It can export a standalone executable in WIndows, iOs, Android as well.